# Ubuntu 11.10 is on external HDD, how to boot (using grub4dos), and which initrd and vmlinuz to use?

Tags: grub2, external-hdd

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on external HDD. How can I boot it?

I used grub4dos before, and it worked with Fedora distributions. Problem I have now is that I don't know which initrd and vmlinuz files to use.

Tried with one I have in /boot directory, but booting did not worked... Can you give me some ideas what to try, do i have to use different initrd and vmlinuz, or I can solve this with other solutions.

Also, just to mention that boot goes to BusyBox v1.18.4 command prompt.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I may not understand your problem.  What does your system do when it fails to boot?  Do you see any error messages?

How is your external drive attached?  If it is USB, are you explicitly booting from USB or is the USB boot priority higher than the internal HDD?

I'm thinking that the initrd and vmlinuz would be the same on either an external or internal drive...but I'm also just learning about Grub2 too.

Finally, perhaps try using grub2 on the external drive instead of grub4dos.

Good Luck,
Randy

Comment: well, ubuntu does not boot. it boots BusyBox v1.18.4, and shows it's command prompt. i installed ubuntu on external hdd to be able use it on notebook or desktop pc. problem is that my notebook does not have possibility to boot from external hdd (toshiba qosmio g20), so i decided to use grub4dos. and it was worked nice when i was using fedora. now i want to switch to ubuntu on same way. thinking that i'm not using correct initrd and vmlinuz...